# How to display a worksheet blank by default and only display result after a click action ? Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to display a worksheet only after an action has been made. For example: Click from a button on another worksheet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a parameter with 4 values and select default value as `blank`

Place all sheets on a dashboard and add the parameter as a filter in all worksheets.

Create one more worksheet with 3 options and add action filters to other worksheets.

Now place all on dashboard, change parameter value and the check the data.